# multiple db connections in one web application good or bad?

Tags: php, mysql

I am in a dilemma about which is the best solution for a problem concerning db connections. The situation is the following:
I have created different web applications that among other services provide sms service. The sms service needs to have sms delivery confirmation. This is accomplished through a callback from the sms service which sends the report for all the web applications to the same address, separating each sms report by specific application id.

The different approaches are:

- Create a web application for the specific address, and then depending from the appilication id open a db connection for the corresponding db and insert the data.
- Create a web application for the specific address and a small db, where I should store all the sms delivery data for all the applications. Every web application should create a new db connection to the small db for getting the relevant data when it needs to.

The first approach is the easier one to accomplish, but I am concerned about the number of different db connections that the app has to persist. The second approach is a bit more complicated for me but avoids the db connections problem. I don' t know if the multiple db connections problem is big enough to drive me to the second approach. 
I would appreciate any suggestions from your experience, or any other workaround.

Comment: Its depending on your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Start with what you think is simple to achieve. If you're worried, benchmark it and see that it holds your expected load patterns.

You said nothing about your expected load (e.g. # of requests/second). Assuming you use PHP and MySQL, my hunch is that the first simple approach will work. PHP does not persist connections to MySQL beyond the scope of a single request (unless you are doing something you really shouldn't) and the overhead on opening/closing connections in MySQL is fairly low. MySQL is also capable of handling a lot of connections in general (depending on configuration of course).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I didn' t try any benchmarking because my main issue is if creating many db connections in one web app is a good or bad practice in general. This general rule will then be implemented in my specific project. Abdulla above in his comment claims that this decision depends on the specific project. So after reading your reply and the next one of Dokic I would implement the first approach do some benchmarking and if it seems necessary I will follow the Dokic 's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I used third approach for one of my projects.
I will explain it in terms of your project.
I have one database for sms delivery notification **sms_delivery**. My service connects only to that one.
I have one database for each application **app1, app2, and so on**.
Then I created a trigger in **sms_delivery** database that would distribute delivery notification to specific application database.

That way you have one db connection but separate databases for application.

:)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, seems very interesting, although I decided in the beginning to follow shevron's suggestion. The only drawback is that I would keep the same data twice (in sms_delivery db and corresponding application db) but it is not a big issue.